# Need help finding a audio amp

Tags: audio, amplifier

first of all I'm a newbie to the whole audio thing. For the longest time I have been using a pair of speakers with a self build amp (not build by me, but a friend) and I'm using it solely in combination with my PC, noting else.

However, since my PC is standing in our living room, I need to use my headphones from time to time. My current setup looks like this.

```
PC => NI AudioKontrol1 - Headphone Out =>Amp => 2x Speakers
PC => NI AudioKontrol1 - Speaker Out  => Headphones
```

The headphone out of the AK1 is toggable, which is why I hooked up my amp to that output, while the headphones are running constantly. This way I can switch to headphone and mute the amp without having to get up and turn down its volume or turn it of. However, the AK1 has a few annoyances and I would love to get away from it. I think the best solution might be to replace the self build amp with a new one.

Now, what I want to achieve would be the following.

A new amp, which should be placed on my desk (plus points if its compact in size) should have at least one input (3.5mm preferred for PC) and two outputs, one for my speakers and one for headphones. The important thing is that if I switch to headphones, the speakers should be silent. (plus points if there is a toggle to switch. Two volume channels would also be acceptable)

The speakers cables currently are like those (http://images.monoprice.com/productlargeimages/27891.jpg), so basically I have four (banana?) jacks on my current amp. I don't know the right term for them.

I looked for a couple of hours now, but I can't find anything that fits my needs. I saw a few headphone amps, but they don't support speaker out (otherwise they would have been perfect) and I don't want to buy an amp and speaker system separately only to be able to switch between speaker and headphones.

If possible I would like to keep the budget below 100€.
Thanks for any suggestions for systems, or what to look for (search terms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more searching, I found this amp.

http://www.amazon.de/Topping-Verst%C3%A4rker-Amplifier-seperat-Decorder/dp/B00FS6LUWS/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top?ie=UTF8

I'll do some more research if it is actually worth the money and if I want to buy it. If it fit's all my needs than I'll accept this answer.

Any input on that, or other suggestions for suitable amps are welcome as I'm really new to all of this.

**Update: 05.04.2016**

I bought the Topping Amp above and it does exactly what I wanted. I've connected my PC Aux to the input cinch on the back, my speakers to the 2 outputs (back panel) and my headphones to the 3.5 jack on the front panel. Now I can choose whether I want to listen via headphones, speakers or both via a button at the front panel. That's pretty much all I wanted. Being able to quickly switch between speakers and headphones without changing the setup.

Comment: This should be an edit to your original question, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into a analogue headphone amp so that you can still use the NI kontrol interface
Something like this http://www.thomann.de/gb/behringer_ha4700_powerplay_proxl_kopfhoererverstaerker.htm  might be apt for the job, but bear in mind that cheap headphone amps add some noise to the amplified signal

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I think it does to much (and is kinda big). I don't need half the stuff it does. The topping was the right choice in the end :)